# How to find coordinates of a triangle with azimuth?

Tags: coordinates, azimuth, triangulation

I am just starting out in GIS and it's been a long time since I took math in university. I am teaching myself through a textbook but there are a few questions I am stumped on.

Essentially I have a triangle. Say one point is A, the other is B and the third is C. I have the coordinates for point A and B. I have the azimuths from A to C and from B to C. I am trying to find out what the coordinates of point C.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Note:** VERY basic math, not a coordinate system or curvature of the Earth. Just the basic concept.

Comment: The method to use depends on several things: how long the distances are, what type of coordinate system you intend to use (projected, geographic), how accurate you need the results to be, etc.

Comment: Have a look at simultaneous equations http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/SystemsofLinEq/EMeth.htm ... you just need to convert your point and bearing into a linear equation. That is for Cartesian mathematics (ignoring the curvature of the earth).